# Optimizing specific memory usage for CUDA

Tags: cuda, memory-optimization

I have a data-processing task, which can be stylized in a following way. I have `data` (~1-10GB), and a function, which generates `summary` (~1MB) based on this `data` and some (double) input `x`. I need to obtain this `summary` for ~1000 values of the `x`, which looked like a perfect task for GPU. To repeat, the input `data` is same for all threads, and is read in a linear fashion, but each thread has to produce his own `summary`. Functions are executed independently for different `x`.

However, brute one-threaded cycling through all values of `x` on CPU yields only 3x worse performance than K520. I do understand that this is memory-intensive task (the threads have to access and write to random parts of his `summary`), but I still struggle to understand how the GPU can lose it's initial 1000x advantage. I've tried feeding the `data` to feeds in chunks using `__constant__` memory (as it's the same input across all threads), with no visible improvement. The typical block run time, as reported by nvprof, is 10-30 seconds.

I would appreciate any insight into the optimizations suitable for this task.

EDIT: Below is a sample code which replicates the problem. It can be compiled under both g++ (reporting run time of 5s) and nvcc (reporting runtime of 7s). The profiling results are as follows

> ==23844== Profiling result:
>   Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
>   98.86%  4.68899s         1  4.68899s  4.68899s  4.68899s  Kernel(Observation*, int*, Info**)
>    1.09%  51.480ms         4  12.870ms  1.9200us  50.426ms  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
>    0.06%  2.6634ms       800  3.3290us  3.2950us  5.1200us  [CUDA memcpy DtoD]
>    0.00%  4.3200us         1  4.3200us  4.3200us  4.3200us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstring>

#define MAX_OBS 1000000
#define MAX_BUCKETS 1000

using namespace std;

// Cross-arch defines
#ifndef __CUDACC__

#define GPU_FUNCTION

#define cudaSuccess 0

typedef int cudaError_t;

struct dim3
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} blockIdx, threadIdx;

enum cudaMemcpyKind
{
    cudaMemcpyHostToDevice = 0,
    cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost = 1, 
    cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice = 2
};

cudaError_t cudaMalloc(void ** Dst, size_t bytes)
{
    return !(*Dst = malloc(bytes));
}

cudaError_t cudaMemcpy(void * Dst, const void * Src, size_t bytes, cudaMemcpyKind kind)
{
    return !memcpy(Dst, Src, bytes);
}

#else
#define GPU_FUNCTION __global__
#endif

// Basic observation structure as stored on disk
struct Observation
{
    double core[20];
};

struct Info
{
    int left;
    int right;
};

GPU_FUNCTION void Kernel(Observation * d_obs, 
                         int * d_bucket,
                         Info ** d_summaries)
{
    Info * summary = d_summaries[threadIdx.x * 40 + threadIdx.y];

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_OBS; i++)
    {
        if (d_obs[i].core[threadIdx.x] < (threadIdx.x + 1) * threadIdx.y)
            summary[d_bucket[i]].left++;
        else
            summary[d_bucket[i]].right++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    // Generate dummy observations
    Observation * obs = new Observation [MAX_OBS];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_OBS; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            obs[i].core[j] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;

    // Attribute observations to one of the buckets
    int * bucket = new int [MAX_OBS];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_OBS; i++)
        bucket[i] = rand() % MAX_BUCKETS;

    Info summary[MAX_BUCKETS];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_BUCKETS; i++)
        summary[i].left = summary[i].right = 0;

    time_t start;
    time(&start);

    // Init device objects
    Observation * d_obs;                    
    int * d_bucket; 
    Info * d_summary;
    Info ** d_summaries;

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_obs, MAX_OBS * sizeof(Observation));
    cudaMemcpy(d_obs, obs, MAX_OBS * sizeof(Observation), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_bucket, MAX_OBS * sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(d_bucket, bucket, MAX_OBS * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_summary, MAX_BUCKETS * sizeof(Info));
    cudaMemcpy(d_summary, summary, MAX_BUCKETS * sizeof(Info), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    Info ** tmp_summaries = new Info * [20 * 40];
    for (int k = 0; k < 20 * 40; k++)           
        cudaMalloc((void**)&tmp_summaries[k], MAX_BUCKETS * sizeof(Info));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_summaries, 20 * 40 * sizeof(Info*));
    cudaMemcpy(d_summaries, tmp_summaries, 20 * 40 * sizeof(Info*), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    for (int k = 0; k < 20 * 40; k++)
        cudaMemcpy(tmp_summaries[k], d_summary, MAX_BUCKETS * sizeof(Info), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice);

#ifdef __CUDACC__
    Kernel<<<1, dim3(20, 40, 1)>>>(d_obs, d_bucket, d_summaries);
#else
    for (int k = 0; k < 20 * 40; k++)
    {
        threadIdx.x = k / 40;
        threadIdx.y = k % 40;
        Kernel(d_obs, d_bucket, d_summaries);
    }
#endif      

    cudaMemcpy(summary, d_summary, MAX_BUCKETS * sizeof(Info), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    time_t end;
    time(&end);
    cout << "Finished calculations in " << difftime(end, start) << "s" << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT 2: I've tried reworking the code by parallelizing tough scattered memory access. To be brief, my new kernel looks like this

```
__global__ void Kernel(Observation * d_obs, 
                         int * d_bucket,
                         double * values,
                         Info ** d_summaries)
{
    Info * summary = d_summaries[blockIdx.x * 40 + blockIdx.y];

    __shared__ Info working_summary[1024];
    working_summary[threadIdx.x] = summary[threadIdx.x];
    __syncthreads();

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_OBS; i++)
    {
        if (d_bucket[i] != threadIdx.x) continue;
        if (d_obs[i].core[blockIdx.x] < values[blockIdx.y])
            working_summary[threadIdx.x].left++;
        else
            working_summary[threadIdx.x].right++;
    }
    __syncthreads();

    summary[threadIdx.x] = working_summary[threadIdx.x];
}
```

This takes 18s for `<<<dim(20, 40, 1), 1000>>>` and 172s for `<<<dim(20,40,10), 1000>>>` --- which is worse that single CPU thread and increases linearly in the number of parallel tasks.

Comment: Usually, a 1000x difference between GPU and CPU means your CPU algorithm is terribly un-optimized. A finely optimized CPU program that uses all the cores and vector units of a modern processor will be about 3x-8x times slower than a finely optimized GPU version, in the general case (YMMV). Now, if you could *please* post some code so we could suggest improvement, because optimizations could come from many different places: Are your memory accesses coalescent? Do you have enough data in flight to keep the GPU busy? Etc.

Comment: Park, I'm benchmarking agaist 1 CPU thread; I also have not optimized the code on a micro level. I'll try to write minimum working example later today, but I want to understand what sort of speedup I should expect with the minimum set of assumptions about the code. To answer your specific questions: memory accesses to __data__ are linear (kernels loop through it from start to finish), but __summary__ is accessed randomly both for reads and for writes (this I fear is the main bottleneck). Data transfers don't figure much in the general picture, nvprof attributes 100% time to kernels.

Comment: You may compare peak FLOPS and peak memory bandwidth of CPU vs GPU for a _rough_ guideline of what your performance ratio may look like. You'll probably end up in the range noted by @ParkYoung-Bae. Anything more certain than that would require you to post code with specific profiling/benchmarking results. Without any code, that's just too open ended.

Comment: Seriously, you are launching *one* block and complaining about poor performance and optimisation?

Comment: Thus is a demonstration version of the code; the original uses more than one block, with no palpable improvement (i.e. almost linear execution time growth from 1 to 10 blocks). I've actually thought it's better to use parallelism in threads than parallelism in blocks. Neverming, I'll add more blocks to the code and benchmark again.

Answer (score 2):

The K520 board you're using has two GPUs, each with 8 Streaming Multiprocessors, with, I beleive, a peak bandwidth of ~160 GB/s per GPU. With the code above you should be limited by this bandwidth, and should be looking at getting at least 100 GB/s per GPU (though I'd target a single GPU to start). Maybe you won't be able to hit it, maybe you'll beat it, but it's a good target to aim for.

### Number of blocks

The first thing to do is to fix your launch parameters. This line:

```
Kernel<<<1, dim3(20, 40, 1)>>>(d_obs, d_bucket, d_summaries);
```

means you're launching 1 CUDA block of 800 threads. This is nowhere near enough parallelism for the GPU. You need **at least** as many blocks as streaming multiprocessors (ie. 8), preferably significantly more (ie. 100+). This will give you a large performance improvement. 800-way parallelism just isn't enough for a GPU.

### Scattered Writes

GPUs can be rather sensitive to access patterns. The following code:

```
summary[d_bucket[i]].left++;
```

does a scattered 4-byte write into summary. Scattered memory transactions are expensive on the GPU, and for reasonable performance on memory bound codes they should be avoided. What can we do about it in this case? The solution is, in my opinion, to add more parallelism. Instead of having a summary per thread, have a summary per **block**. Each thread can work on a subset of the range `0...MAX_OBS`, and can increment the block-wide summary array which should be located in `shared memory`. At the end of the kernel you can write the result back to global memory. Happily, this also solves your lack of parallelism problem noted above!

### What next?

At this point you should figure out a way to measure how much room for improvement there is. You'll want to work out how close to peak bandwidth you are (I find it's best to consider both data you have to move, and data you are actually moving), and if you're still significantly off it, you want to look at both reducing memory accesses and optimising accesses further, if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the meaningful answer. Here are the benchmarks again: scaling from 1 to 10 to 100 blocks in the above example gets me 8s/75s/745s on CPU (perfectly linear, as expected), and 5s/19s/186s on GPU. Note that the parallelism is poor from 1 to 10 and non-existent from 10 to 100 blocks. Those are more or less the issues I've encountered on the production code as well. With 100 blocks, we are talking 100k threads, and yet GPU offers only 4x performance of _single CPU thread_. Given that you can get a 28 core server right now, this seems very poor. Is this a wrong type of task for GPU?

Comment: One additional comment. The problem appears to be a form of histogramming. I haven't studied the code closely, but I'd be surprised if the GPU and CPU versions of the code produce identical results (particularly if you extend to more than 1 block). Your huge for-loop in the kernel suggests some possibilities for breaking the work into smaller pieces that can be distributed amongst more threads and blocks. But the histogram aspect of it (scattered writes) may be challenging. If you can re-cast the problem into a type of histogram that can be handled by thrust or cub, it may be your best option.

Comment: I've editted my answer with a suggestion on how to tackle the scattered access that's causing you problems. As @RobertCrovella says though, it may be there is a library that can help you instead of this. Also - I'd suggest avoiding 1-block examples if possible - as you yourself found you get a 4x improvement from simply adding more blocks, which is quite a lot to start with!

Comment: Robert -- The sample code is indeed a form of (rather pointless) histogramming; the real production code does something similar, but more complicated, so using thrust/cub does not seem to be an option. Breaking 'data' into smaller pieces is possible, but will multiply memory consumption (already at limits in production code). It is also my opinion that scattered writes are killing the performance.

Comment: Jez -- thanks for reworking the answer. I'll rewrite the example with 10 blocks-benchmark to make performance difference less scandalous :) I believe you are correct in identifying the problem, but I was reluctant to rewrite it in the manner you suggest because I thought I'll kill per-block parallelism and will gain little. Let me try it now and report back.

Comment: Jez -- I've added a new edit with workload sharing between threads in one block, each thread working on his own bucket in the summary. There is no way I can paralellize on the observations as well, as all my threads are busy just filling summary in parallel.